# C3js and D3js Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(0,NaN)"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I'm trying to create a bunch of panels with d3js and then trying to fill those panels with graphs using C3js. For some reason, I keep getting:

```
Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(0,NaN)"
```

When I hardcode the panels, it works just fine. Here is some example code that shows the error: https://jsfiddle.net/tgp9gqfb/2/

Any direction on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can't answer, but the problem seems related to the kind of data `x_graph_wrapper' is bound to. Reduced example : https://jsfiddle.net/sysvtm40/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing it with setting data and making divs:

```
d3.select("#page-wrapper").selectAll("div")
            .data(order_labels["a"]);
```

Do the same with a for loop:

```
  order_labels["a"].forEach(function(d) {
    new_panels = d3.select("#page-wrapper").append('div').attr('class', "panel panel-default");
    new_panels.append('div').attr('class', "panel-heading").text(function() {
      return readable_lables[d];
    });
    new_panels.append('div').attr('class', "panel-body").append('div').attr("id", function() {
      return d + "graph_wrapper";
    });
    new_panels.append('div').attr('class', "panel-footer");
  });
```

I agree the way you doing is correct but the internal c3 error is because of the data in the div that is the reason why i am asking you to do the same with the for loop.

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/4erq0jof/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Cyril and Jean. The reason was because the data array were string values and for some reason the C3js module wasn't handling it properly. Your answer represents a valid workaround. Could you add the fact that it was because of the strings?